# Can a team sell tickets to a practice?

Tags: rules, baseball, mlb, fans

The Tigers have about a week off between now and the World Series.  Is there anything in the Rules about not letting a Team Sell Tickets for Practice?  My thought is that by having a stadium full of fans would feel more like a real game and keep the players in the mindset they have during the season.  They wouldn't necessary have to sell tickets but just a way to basically have an open inter team game?

**EDIT** (from comment below): I was thinking more of the inter squad games they were playing. They would still have their closed off from public so they could concentrate on how to play the other team. The Inter Squd game with a crowd would give the feeling that it is just a regular season game and keep them in that mind set

Comment: Why was `football` ever tagged to this question? The OP is clearly asking about baseball (specifically the MLB).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is **Yes.**

Every team can decide to sell tickets for training, I can give you an example from soccer since I'm not familiar with MLB.

Most of the time the income from friendly games or training goes to charity.

Real Madrid practice on there US tour cost between $85-382 as you can read at the following [link](http://sports.yahoo.com/blogs/soccer-dirty-tackle/real-madrid-charge-fans-85-382-watch-ucla-205018390--sow.html).

Comment: Would like to know if it has happened in MLB.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure the players don't want the distraction of a thousand people yelling and cheering at them, wanting autographs/etc while they are trying to prepare for the biggest game of their careers.

More importantly, they could be going through things in regards of how to play against the other team. Naturally, they don't want outsiders to see this type of thing.

To answer your actual question, a team can sell tickets to whatever it wants from games to practices to a press conference.

Comment: I was thinking more of the inter squad games they were playing.  They would still have their closed off from public so they could concentrate on how to play the other team.  The Inter Squd game with a crowd would give the feeling that it is just a regular season game and keep them in that mind set

Comment: @Ticky Are there any examples/evidence of this you can provide?

Answer (score 0):

I can't find any law that restricts the teams from selling tickets to practice however none of the teams actually sell tickets to training. Sometimes the team will let fans come to practice.

Comment: Are there any examples of this you can provide?